# Export to excel adds additional columns and merges them

Tags: reporting-services

I have created one report which contains three matrix and one table. First matrix is at the top and below that I have one table and two matrix adjacent to that.
Everything is aligned properly. When I export to excel few columns are getting merged and user doesn't want that to happen. I tried multiple solution from here but it hasn't worked.

When I remove the two matrix placed below the one which is at the top then there is no issue, however when I add them again then excel generates additional columns when exported from ssrs.

Please any solution on this?

Comment: This is the nature of the Export. Visualize the textboxes, tablix columns, and all other controls in a grid. Unless everything lines up exactly to a cell, it's likely they are going to get merged. Even if one control is 0.0001 inches off from another, it might cause merged cells in Excel.

Comment: Okay, I will try aligning everything and let you know if still there is issue.